# internal and external logging in Jetty Log4j

Tags: java, log4j, jetty

I have a requirement of maintaining 2 sets of logging.

1. Jetty's logging using log4j.xml: which is happening properly with my custom LoggingLayout. The file is placed in {jetty.base}/resources folder.

```
  <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="true" />
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
      <param name="fileNamePattern" value="${jetty.base}/logs/DataModeler_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log" />
    </rollingPolicy>
    <param name="file" value="${jetty.base}/logs/DataModeler.log" />
    <param name="datePattern" value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.log'" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.LoggingLayout"/>
  </appender>
```

The war file log4j.properties file, which is placed in WEB-INF folder, is as follows:

```
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=logs/UniqueLogger.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.rollingFile.append=true

log4j.rootCategory=ALL, rollingFile
```

I tried with log4j.appender.rollingFile.File={jetty.base}/logs/UniqueLogger.log in the war file's log4j.properties, but it doesn't work.

2. I also need to produce the deployed war file logging. I mean there is internal logging in the java project which is packaged into war file.

I can not figure out any way in which I can produce the 2nd set of log files for the internal logger in the war file.

Comment: Jetty does not use log4j for it's logging.  Have you setup your Jetty server to use slf4j -> log4j perhaps?

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt yes. I followed these steps: 1. java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar --add-to-start=http,deploy,resources,ext

Comment: 2. # Download the required jar files
$ cd /path/to/mybase/lib/ext
$ curl -O http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar
$ curl -O http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.7.21/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar
$ curl -O http://central.maven.org/maven2/log4j/log4j/1.2.17/log4j-1.2.17.jar 3. $ cd /path/to/mybase/resources
$ echo "org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.class=org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog" > jetty-logging.properties
4. cd /path/to/mybase/resources --> created log4j.xml 5. start the server: java -jar /path/to/jetty-dist/start.jar

Comment: So Jetty is successfully able to generate the log files. But the internal logging in the War file is not generating any logs.

Comment: Here is the log4j.properties in the war file, which is placed in WEB-INF folder:
log4j.appender.rollingFile=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.rollingFile.File=logs/UniqueNameLogger.log
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.rollingFile.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %m%n
log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxFileSize=10MB

Comment: log4j.appender.rollingFile.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.rollingFile.append=true
 
log4j.rootCategory=ALL, rollingFile

Comment: also in the start.ini file, did this modification: ```--module=logging-log4j```. which can be achieved by java -jar start.jar --add-to-start=logging-log4j

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt my log messages like debug/info are different from the console.. am I doing anything wrong.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt please provide any update on this.